# Swift 3: Calling Step Count Query from Health Kit

Tags: swift, xcode, function, swift3, healthkit

Updated: I am trying to call on a function that accesses the HealthKit and returns the number of steps taken that day.

I have created a function and now I am trying to call it. The code for the function is as follows:

```
//Reading data from Health app.
func todayTotalSteps (input: String, completion: @escaping (_ stepRetrieved: Double) -> Void){

    // Define the Step Quantity Type.
    let stepsCount = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)

    // Get the start of the day.
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    let newDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: date as Date)
    let yesterday = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())
    let now = Date()

    // Set the predicates & interval
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: newDate as Date, end: NSDate() as Date, options: .strictStartDate)
    let interval: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

    interval.day = 1

    //Perform the Query
    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: stepsCount!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.cumulativeSum], anchorDate: newDate as Date, intervalComponents: interval as DateComponents)
    query.initialResultsHandler = {query, results, error in

        if error != nil {
            // Something went wrong.
            return
        }

        if let  myResults = results{
            myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: yesterday! as Date, to: now as Date){
                statistics, stop in

                if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity(){
                    let steps = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())

                    print("Steps = \(steps)")
                    completion(steps)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    healthStore.execute(query)


}
```

I am creating a button action and inside it I am trying to call the todayTotalSteps function. I have enabled HealthKit permissions in a different function. Running the app on my iPhone 5 works fine until I add the function todayTotalSteps and the button with its action, then when I tap the button I added, I get the following error and nothing else happens. In the debug area it says:

"HealthkitAccess[267:13336] [query] Error activating query: Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=5 "Authorization not determined" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization not determined}"

The button function is written below:

```
@IBAction func getSteps(_ sender: Any) {
    todayTotalSteps(input: "commands"){stepRetrieved in print(stepRetrieved)
}
```

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8. I am new to swift and I would really appreciate any insight to get this to work! Thanks!

Comment: Count your curly braces. You need the same number of open and close curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func getSteps(_ sender: Any) {
    todayTotalSteps(input: "commands") { stepRetrieved in
        print(stepRetrieved) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I thought that my only problem was with not being able to call the function in my button but the function itself does not work. Would you be able to re-look at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The new HK requires you to ask for the user's permission before fetching any sort of data. 
In their new update, they mentioned:

> "Important An iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include in its
>   Info.plist file the usage description keys for the types of data it
>   needs to access or it will crash. To access and update HealthKit data
>   specifically, it must include the NSHealthShareUsageDescription and
>   NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription keys, respectively."
>   https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit